# SQL Server : an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'

Tags: sql-server

Getting this error with the following query in SQL Server 2012.

```
AND Invoice_Header.Invoice_date >= '2005-02-28'  
AND(LTRIM(RTRIM(@carrierselect)))
--Error on this line of code
AND CATEGORY IN ('MEDP', 'MEDG')
AND invoice_status_code <> 'L'
```

Comment: are you sure, that your variable `@carrierselect` is a bit datatype?

Comment: Even if `@carrierselect` is a bit type, it will still produce the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
AND(LTRIM(RTRIM(@carrierselect)))
```

You do not have any comparison that will result to a boolean value. You must have forgotten to put something there:

```
AND(LTRIM(RTRIM(@carrierselect))) = 'something'
```